# std::string returning inappropriate value

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I wrote a program which perform string compression using counts of repeated characters. The program in C++ is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
std::string compressBad(std::string str)
{
    std::string mystr = "";
    int count = 1;
    char last = str[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length();++i)
    {
        if(str[i] == last)
            count++;
        else
        {
            std::string lastS = last+"";
            std::string countS = std::to_string(count);
            mystr.append(lastS);
            mystr.append(countS);
            //mystr = mystr + last + count;
            count = 1;
            last = str[i];
        }
    }
    std::string lastS = last+"";
    std::string countS = std::to_string(count);
    mystr.append(lastS);
    mystr.append(countS);
    return mystr;        
    //return mystr+last+count;
}
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::string str2 = compressBad(str);
    std::cout<<str2;
    /*if (str.length() < str2.length())
        std::cout<<str;
    else
        std::cout<<str2;*/
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Few example on running this are :

```
Input : sssaaddddd

Output : ùÿÿ*425

Output it should print : s3a2d5
```

Second example:

```
Input : sssaaddd

Output: ùÿÿ*423 

Output it should print : s3a2d3
```

I also implemented the same concept in Java and there it is working fine. The java implementation is [here](http://ideone.com/d5evOi)

Why is this problem happening with above code.

Comment: *I also implemented the same concept in Java and there it is working fine.*  -- The moral of the story -- C++ is *not* Java.  Do not use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  The answers below shows the trouble you get into when thinking that the same code in Java works the same as in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be other issues in your code, but I think that this line might be to blame:

```
std::string lastS = last+"";
```

Here, you're trying to convert the character `last` to a string by concatenating the empty string to the end. Unfortunately, in C++ this is interpreted to mean "take the numeric value of the character `last`, then add that to a pointer that points to the empty string, producing a new pointer to a character." This pointer points into random memory, hence the garbage you're seeing. (Notice that this is *quite* different from how Java works!)

Try changing this line to read

```
std::string lastS(1, last);
```

This will initialize `lastS` to be a string consisting of just the character stored in `last`.

Another option would be to use an `ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream myStr;
myStr << last << count;

// ...

return myStr.str();
```

This eliminates all the calls to `.append()` and `std::to_string` and is probably a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

`last + ""` doesn't do what you think.

just do

```
mystr.append(1, last);
```